# How would I make the UI thread run continuously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom-events

From what I understand, because JavaScript is single-threaded, an action like

```
setTimeout(0, function() { alert("Hello"); });
```

will not block the UI thread, will wait until there's a break in the UI thread so that it can "jump in" and run. This is the old JavaScript saying

> "When there's nothing to do, check the [callback] queue. But only
>   check the queue when there's nothing to do."

What I'm saying is, can someone show me an example where the browser always has something to do and therefore the asynchronous methods in the callback queue are never executed? Or is my understanding of the event loop completely warped?

Comment: `while(true); // Haha no other threads can jump in now!`

Comment: Change to another tab.

Comment: Your sample code is borked. You've got the order of the arguments reversed. Also, the minimum timeout varies across browsers. FireFox uses a 4ms minimum, iirc. That said, they also have a non-standard `setImmediate()` function which queues up the callback to execute as soon as possible. At any rate, if something is blocking indefinitely ([and it's certainly possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954803/how-would-i-make-the-ui-thread-run-continuously#comment57641254_34954803)), you've got bigger problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out callbacks are done when the browser has nothing else to do. If callbacks were never run the user would perceive the browser as non responsive. This a possible situation though unlikely to be considered normal.

It is perfectly fine to implement your code with the assumption that your timeout callback will occur.  What you do want to do it create an implementation that is tolerant of the callbacks occurring with some time variance. The variance would be related to the longest time spent handling other callbacks and events.